# Footnote marks and Footnotes with specific numbers

Tags: footnotes

I have the following code to create specific footnotes with roman numerals:

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}

\newcommand{\fixedFootnote}[2]{
\let\oldthefootnote=\thefootnote
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\roman{footnote}}
\footnote[#1]{#2}
\let\thefootnote=\oldthefootnote
}
```

It works like a charm.

**PROBLEM:** I can't reference it using `\footnotemark`. I have tried the following and all of them throw errors and do not compile (or put a 0 in the footnote):

- `\footnotemark[\value{ii}]` breaks
- `\footnotemark[\roman{2}]` also breaks
- `\footnotemark[ii]` also breaks

How can I make `\footnotemark` reference my `\fixedFootnote` ?

**EDIT:** I cannot use `\footnormark` with a `\ref` because some templates, like the one I am using, break this command.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `\footnotemark` is not taking a text argument in its optional argument (likewise `\footnote`) but rather a *numerical* argument. Internally, LaTeX takes the optional argument to `\footnotemark` and assigns the footnote counter to the value to the number provided and then creates a footnote mark using `\thefootnote`.

You talk about wanting to refer to footnotes. It's worth noting that you would use the same mechaism to referring to a footnote by number that you would for any other numbered element in the document, just being sure to put the `\label` inside the body of the footnote itself:

```
\footnote{blah blah.\label{myfootnote}}
...
see note~\ref{myfootnote}
```

As you noted in your self-answer, if you want the reference to be superscripted (which I would not recommend), you could write instead `\textsuperscript{\ref{myfootnote}}` which should give you nearly identical formatting to the normal footnote mark (which would be obtained by adding `\normalfont` before the `\ref` so that, e.g., in italicized or bold text, the footnote marker is not italicized or emboldened.

Comment: This is a valid answer. However, the problem is that some templates (like the one I'm using, `elsclass`) break the reference in a footnotemark. It also breaks the `\textsuperspscript` and the reference. Thus, I'm not accepting it because it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: If you leave out information central to your problem in your question, you're unlikely to get the answer you want.

Comment: Fair enough. I did edit the question to add that piece of information.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not the best solution, I ended up doing:

`\textsuperscript{ii}`

replacing the `ii` by the number I wanted to reference.

Answer (score 0):

It is maybe too late now but I'll add an answer. Since you are using two kinds of footnotes I suppose each one should have its own counter and they should be separated in the footer. If I'm correct, then `manyfoot` is what you want. It provides a command to define new footnotes

```
\DeclareNewFootnote[⟨footnote style⟩]{⟨suffix⟩}[⟨enumeration style⟩]
```

In an example it works like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\textheight=90pt%just for the example
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{R}[roman]
\begin{document}
Text\footnote{a footnote} more text\footnoteR{another footnote}

Text\footnotemark more text\footnotemarkR
\footnotetext{more footnotes} \footnotetextR{the last footnote}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the [manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/manyfoot) you can see many more features of this package